# Evans' PDE Problem 7 Chapter 3 - Noncharacteristic condition in the case boundary is not flat near the initial datum

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In Evans' PDE book, chapter 3.2 (which you can consult [here](https://docdro.id/Lvfpp5i)), it is presented the method of characteristic to solve the first order PDE
\begin{cases}
F(Du,u,x)=0 &\text{in }U \subset \mathbb R^n\\
u=g &\text{on }\Gamma,
\end{cases}
(where $\Gamma \subseteq \partial U$ and $g:\Gamma \to \mathbb R$ are given) by converting the PDE into a system of ODE. After deriving the characteristic equations, it is introduced the flattening of the boundary so that the initial problem can be solved in a neighborhood of the initial datum $x^0 \in \Gamma$. Then the compatibility conditions are derived for a triple $(p^0,z^0,x^0)$ of initial conditions, and the compatibility conditions (equations (33) and (34) in the pdf linked above) are derived also for points near the said triple. Then we have the following lemma

[image]

which holds only for $\Gamma$ flat near $x^0$. For the case $\Gamma$ not flat near $x^0$ we have

[image]

and Problem 7 asks to prove the condition (36).

Could you give any hints to solve the problem?